# Error 500: How to get session variable via Laravel custom config file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use a custom config file to access a session variable – or a fallback if not set.

But I get an **HTTP ERROR 500** once i add Session::get()

> [05-May-2016 19:53:16] PHP Deprecated:  Non-static
>   method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session::has() should
>   not be called statically in
>   /Users/.../config/constants.php

What's wrong?

```
<?php
// File: app/config/constants.php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;


$something = Session::has('something') ? Session::get('something') : "fallback";


return [
    'something ' => $something
];
```

**Update 1:**

```
use Session;
```

results in this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message
>   'Class log does not exist' in
>   /Users/…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:738
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Users/…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(738):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('log') #1
>   /Users/…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(633):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array) #2
>   /Users/…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array) #3
>   /Users/…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(853):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Psr\Log\LoggerI...') #4
>   /Users/…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illum
>   in
>   /Users/…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>   on line 738

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Try just `use Session;` to import the `Session` facade.

Comment: I've added the logs: Session::has() should not be called statically

Comment: use Session; results in another error. See update 1.

Answer (score 3):

You should be `use`ing the `Facade` from the `Illuminate\Support` package.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Then you can correctly use `Session::`

Comment: Still get this error: [05-May-2016 19:59:58] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /Users/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:738

Comment: @fabian That has nothing to do with the Session. it says class **log** does not exist. Given that the issue has to do with other code that's incorrectly formatted and we've resolved the current issue, please consider upvoting and accepting my answer.

Comment: Yes and No. If i delete the Session::has() line I dont' get the the error. So the log-error is related to session?!

Comment: I've just checked the entire sourcecode of the `Illuminate\Support` library, and there's no reference to any class of `log`.

Comment: @fabian Check your `.env` file for any unnecessary spaces or incorrectly escaped strings.

Comment: .env file looks fine.

Comment: @fabian Check your other `config` files. Show your entire stack trace.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this issue before. It's not what you think that it is. Instead, it's an issue with one of your files in your `config` directory. Review the adjustments you've made carefully.

Comment: I already broke it down. Once I add  Session::has('something') everything crashes :-(

Comment: @fabian I really think you need to take a closer look at those files. Dump out the session, trace again. I'm certain the issue is with a configuration problem

Comment: This article seems related to my problem: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-log-does-not-exist?page=1

Comment: @fabian After reading through that, it re-enforces some of the thoughts that I had. Do come back and let me know what the issue was (if you do resolve it).

Comment: I am running PHP Version 5.5.27. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Same Problem with php 7.0.0 :(

Comment: Same problem with a fresh installation of laravel 5.2

Comment: "php artisan config:cache" fixed the error message. But Session::has('something') and Session::get('something') is always empty. If i print the session-var I can see the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access session in config file in laravel the alternative solutions is to store your session variable in a cookie and then access that cookie in config file.
Use $_COOKIE php array to access cookies.